# SwipeRefreshLayout не даёт скроллить вниз не раскрытый AppBarLayout показывая вместо этого индикатор загрузки после обновления support до 23.2.0

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

После обновления гугловых библиотек до  `23.2.0` столкнулся с проблеммой, коя была в старых их версиях (если не ошибаюсь, это `22+` или `23.1.0`)

У меня `RecyclerView` в `SwipeRefreshLayout`, коий, в свою очередь, в `CoordinatorLayout` в котором `AppBarLayout` с `CollapsingToolbarLayout` внутри.

И когда у меня `CollapsingToolbarLayout` не полностью раскрыт и я пытаюсь его раскрыть скроллом вниз, то вместо этого получаю появление индикатора загрузки  `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Что же делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, похоже это баг старый-новый баг `23.2.0` версии support библиотеки.

Достаточно откатить версии библиотек до `23.1.1` чтобы баг исчез.

Придётся ждать очередного баг-фикса от гугла и пользоваться пока старой версией

Вот список зависимостей, кои не строит обновлять до `23.2.0` во избежания сего бага:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

---

Также можно воспользоваться [костылём](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35643170/3212712) переопределения `SwipeRefreshLayout`

---

Вот ссылка на баг в багтрекере гугла: [RecyclerView v23.2.0 - doesn't play nicely with SwipeRefreshLayout](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201775)

---

Этот же вопросо-ответ на англо-саксонском:
[SwipeRefreshLayout prevents AppBarLayout scrolling down with showing refresh circle after updating support libs to 23.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638081/)

---

**UPD 08.04.2016:**

Проблема исправлена в версии библиотек `23.3.0`