# Не виден индикатор загрузки SwipeRefreshLayout при пустом адаптере ListView

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, swiperefreshlayout

При заходе в активность срабатывает новый поток с загрузкой и индикатор загрузки не виден до тех пор, пока адаптер у `ListView` пуст. При обновлении всё отображается корректно. Включение и отключение анимации происходит в методах `onPreExecute()` и `onPostExecute()` соответственно.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ...            
        SwipeRefreshLayout SRL = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.srl);
        SRL.setRefreshing(true);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ...            
        SwipeRefreshLayout SRL = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.srl);
        SRL.setRefreshing(false);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему своего рода кешированием данных. При открытии `Activity` выполняется парсинг и заполнение адаптера из кеша. А после уже выполняется поток на загрузку (обновление) данных, в котором уже всё отображается как надо.

**UPD**

Проблема не возникает если не использовать `listView.setAdapter(null);`, а передавать адаптер с пустым массивом данных. **Это применимо и к `RecyclerView`**.

Comment: А если это первый запуск и нет кэша или он был юзером вручную удалён?

Comment: Думал и на счёт этого, решил при первой загрузке не отображать ничего. Но это малые жертвы для "большого успеха".

Answer (score 2):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` дико глючный и регулярно ломаемый гуглом в обновлениях библиотек поддержки. За долгие годы так и не удалось найти нормального решения этой проблемы. В качестве временного костыля можно предложить лишь отложенное исполнение метода `setRefreshing` в другом потоке так:

```
//workaround from
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/26910973/3212712
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(isLoading);
    }
});
```

При этом, если уйти с активити/закрыть фрагмент до отмены кружочка (интернет медленный, юзер устал ждать), то он может вообще не исчезнуть с экрана, т.к. был на него добавлен  другом потоке.

Так что, возможно, вам надо вовсе отказаться от ручного вызова кружочка и заменить его своей реализацией индикатора загрузки, оставив кружочек только для возможности "потянуть чтоб обновить"

Comment: SRL [был добавлен](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions) в suport.v4 с версии 19.1.0 от марта 2014 и с тех пор  фиксился только один раз в ревизии suport.v4 20.0 в июле того же года, так что насчет долгих лет и регулярных переделок вы немного погорячились все же :) . Насчет глючности не скажу, не приходилось использовать

Comment: @pavlofff, я не проверял что и когда там фиксилось, но он точно ломался в какой-то версии до 21.1.1 и потом в версии 23.2.0. Вот, я даже писал об этом: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497162/17609

Comment: Ну а так - да, я порою бываю излишне категоричен - уж очень много крови мне этот виджет в своё время попортил)